# sed: insert a string after every N lines

Tags: sed

I want to insert a string after every 30 lines in my large file. I'm using mini-sed, which doesn't support ~ (tilde) range operator. I'm looking for sed-only solution please.

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons, but it's hard to not suggest `awk` here.

Comment: Actually i'm not sure he has a reason.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath http://www.exactcode.com/site/open_source/minised/

I'm sure he has a lot of reasons

Comment: @user1207217: enlighten me..

Answer (score 53):

This thread is another example of how to over complicate things. This should do it:

```
sed '0~30 s/$/string/g' < inputfile > outputfile
```

Every 30 lines "string" is inserted at the end of the line. If you want a new line with the word "string" just use "\n string".

Comment: 'thread' is never the right word for a Stack Overflow page. I take your point, but you are talking about 'the other answers to this question'. :-)

Comment: Although this was what I wanted, the asker specifically asked for solutions not using tilde.

Comment: This did not work: sed '0~5000 s/$/\n commit;/g'  < batch.sql > batch-commit.sql      
sed: 1: "0~5000 s/$/\n commit;/g": invalid command code ~

Comment: Probably way too late for you but I think the issue is you need to delimit the semicolon -  sed '0~5000 s/$/\n commit\;/g'

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
sed '1~30 i everyThirtyLine' file.dat
```

This is tested in Cygwin.

Answer (score 7):

This inserts a line every 3 lines;

```
seq 1 10 | sed ': loop; n; n; a insert
n; b loop'
```

Producing

```
1
2
3
insert
4
5
6
insert
7
8
9
insert
10
```

adjust the number of `n;` commands before the `a` command accordingly

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 'n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;s/$/\ 
string/' filename
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Is there a shorter way. To insert every 100 lines, I want to avoid specifying 'n' 100 times.

Comment: @user868923, short answer: no, at that point you're really using the wrong tool. You *could* use sed to *construct* that string of n's and then run it, but it would be a sed command so arcane that it would really only be good for impressing other wizards. Hmm...

Answer (score 2):

**Begin Edit**

The initial solution bellow needs as much memory in the hold space as the size of the N lines.  This is a better solution that only keeps `'\n'` in the hold space instead of all the lines, needing much less memory:

```
sed -e 'p;G;s/[^\n]//g;t next;:next;s/^\n\{5\}$//;t insert;h;d;:insert;x;s/^.*$/new line/' your_large_file
```

The same can be done using the i command that is less known than the s command:

```
sed -e 'p;G;s/[^\n]//g;t next;:next;s/^\n\{5\}$//;t insert;h;d;:insert;x;i \
new line
d' your_large_file
```

Again, the explained version that can be run with `'sed -f script your_large_file'`:

```
# Whatever happen afterward, the current line need to be printed.
p
# Append the hold space, that contains as much \n as the number of lines read since the text has been added.
G
# Keeps only the \n in the pattern space.
s/[^\n]//g
# The 't next' bellow is needed so the 't insert' will not take into account the s command above.
t next
:next
# If we have exaclty 5 \n in the patern space, empty the hold space and insert the text, else save the pattern space for next cycle.
# In both cases, end the current cycle without printing the pattern space.
s/^\n\{3\}$//
t insert
h
d
:insert
x
i \
new line
d
```

**End Edit**

The following script will add `'\nnew line'` after each 5 lines.  If you want to do it every 6 or 100 lines, just change the `'\{5\}'` by `'\{6\}'` or `'\{100\}'`.

```
sed -n -e 'H;g;s/[^\n]//g;t next;:next;s/^\n\{5\}$//;t insert;$ {x;s/^\n//;p};b;:insert;x;s/$/\nnew line/;s/^\n//;p' your_large_file
```

This deserves some explanations, so bellow is a commented script file version .  It must be run with `'sed -n -f script your_large_file'`.

```
H
g
# Now, the pattern and hold space contain what has been read so far with an extra \n at the beginning.
s/[^\n]//g
# Now, the pattern space only contains \n, the hold space is unmodified.
# The 't next' bellow is needed so the 't insert' will not take into account the s command above.
t next
:next
# If we have exactly 5 new lines in the pattern space, the hold space is printed without the \n at the beginning and with the text to added after 5 lines at its end.
s/^\n\{5\}$//
t insert
# If not 5 \n and at the last line, the hold space must be printed without the \n at its beginning.
$ {x;s/^\n//;p}
b
:insert
x
# Now the hold space is empty and ready to receive new lines as the pattern space has been emptied by the 2 s commands above.
s/$/\nnew line/
s/^\n//
p
```

Comment: Take a look at [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43579719/900078) which is simpler. :)

Answer (score 2):

This inserts a line after every 3 lines.

```
[STEP 101] # cat insert.sed
# add one more 'x' into the hold space
x
s/^/x/
t reset_t_cond
: reset_t_cond
# check if there are 3 'x' chars now
s/x\{3\}//
x
t insert
b

: insert
a\
INSERT HERE
[STEP 102] # seq 10 | sed -f insert.sed
1
2
3
INSERT HERE
4
5
6
INSERT HERE
7
8
9
INSERT HERE
10
[STEP 103] #
```