# SQLCMD scripting error

Tags: sqlcmd

i am using SQLCMD to run a .sql file which is 270 MB. The script file (.sql) was generated using Red Gate SQL Data Compare synchronization wizard. I cannot run it from SSMS because of insufficient memory. I log into the server and go to command prompt and it opens up command prompt

> C:\Users\USER1>

then i type in

```
> C:\Users\USER1>SQLCMD -U sa -P PWD -d DATA_FEAT -i F:\SYNC\DATA-DATA_FEAT-20140709.sql -o F:\SYNC\DATA-DATA_FEAT-20140709result.txt
```

but i get

> Sqlcmd: Error: Scripting error.

i am able to use Red gate to synchronize it without error. Red gate runs the same .sql file

Any Help

Thanks

Comment: I suspect the file size is a problem. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224830/how-do-i-set-a-sql-server-scripts-timeout-from-within-the-script) question?

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this with a big script doing a lot of inserts. The solution [was over in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/666872/157247): Insert a `GO` periodically in the file so that everything wasn't being built up in one massive transaction. That answer even got the info from...[a RedGate forum thread](https://forums.red-gate.com/viewtopic.php?t=8109).

Since I'm using Linux and my file was one-statement-per-line, it was quite easy for me to use `sed` as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6880598/157247) to add `GO` every few lines, e.g.:

```
$ sed ': loop; n; n; n; n; n; n; n; n; n; a GO
n; b loop' < bigfile.sql > bigfile2.sql
```

That inserts a GO every 10 lines (the number of times `n` appears in the `sed` script), which is probably overkill.

Comment: SQL Server is now old and sucks unfortunately - so sad we have to resort to this

Comment: Great answer, thanks!
For Windows-users: an easy way to add the GO statements is using the Macro function of Notepad++.
- Click the Record button
- Type the following keys: [PgDwn], [Home], [Enter], [Up-key], type GO
- Click the Stop button
- Click the 'Run Macro multiple times' button
- Select 'Run until end of file' and click Run
- Remove possible extra GO's and empty line at the end of the file
- Save

Comment: @nozem Not if your file is over 3 gigs large :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an SQL file with 2.2M inserts.

Adding GO every few lines as suggested above didn't solve it for me I ended up having to split the file into smaller ones of xxx lines and running them seperately using the bash split command as follows: -

```
split -l xxx largefile.txt newfile.txt
```

I also have a nicer syntax for the sed solution listed above

```
sed '50~50i\GO' largefile.txt > newfile.txt
```

This will insert GO every 50 lines in a file and output the result to a new file.

Hope it helps someone.