# SQLCMD to T-SQL (out of memory and scripting error)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, out-of-memory, sqlcmd

I have over 18GB of database `.sql` file, which have over 200 Millions records. My server have Xeon E5 processor, 16GB ECC RAM and SSDs. I have SQL Server 2014 Web Edition and Windows Server 2012.

I know I would need `sqlcmd` to run huge database so my command is this

```
sqlcmd -S SQL-Server2014 -i C:\main_db.sql -d newtest -o D:\main_db_log.txt
```

When I start this command, `T-SQL command line utility` start working it's magic. But after few minutes it use full 16GB of RAM and server crashes.

`main_db_log.txt` show's this error

`Sqlcmd: Error: Scripting error.`

I tried to restrict SQL Server to use only `10GB` by limiting memory in `ServerInstance` > `Properties` > `Memory Tab` but it didn't work.

I researched around but only found out about `sqlcmd` to run large databases but it's not working in my case.

Please help, because our old server crashed and I can't make `.bak` file there anymore.

Comment: One doesn't "execute" a database (although I have a few I wouldn't mind taking out hunting....). You've not given enough information about the database or the query(ies) you're running or even what you're really trying to achieve for people to guess here.

Comment: @alroc: Sorry about word `execute`, I am a newbie with Databases. I just want to add the whole database's records in `newtest` in MS SQL Server 2014 but I only used the single line above `sqlcmd`. Still having memory issues and scripting error.

Comment: Again, without seeing what your query(ies) are **actually doing**, it's impossible to even guess. You've got an error related your script - so show the script and maybe we can find the error. How big is `main_db.sql`? Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665757/sqlcmd-scripting-error and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16763/how-do-i-run-a-large-script-with-many-inserts-without-running-out-of-memory/

Comment: there are only `insert` commands on each line with just two columns, 1st is `id` and second is `sales_id` and database slze is `18GB`. I saw the questions you recommended, should I use `GO` every 1000 lines?

Comment: If you have tens of thousands of `INSERT` statements yes, it would make sense to break them into smaller batches.

Comment: @alroc: Thanks so much for help, I will try to do it now. Will update here as well. Thanks again

Comment: @TT. yeah let me delete that one.

Comment: I just deleted the other one :) please don't flag this one. I also thought dba was the place for this. but no one was replying there.

Comment: now I have another issue, let me update my question.